# How to fix "ENOTDIR" error when publishing to AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I am trying to push our latest code to our AWS Amplify project in the cloud. The other dev on our team does `amplify publish` and everything pushes to the cloud fine. When I do `amplify publish` it throws an `ENOTDIR` error. I feel like that means I am missing a dependency or a dependency got corrupted or something? I am at a loss.

I have tried doing `amplify codegen`, `amplify env pull --restore`, and I have tried removing and reading the @aws-amplify/cli package that I installed to my app directory with yarn when first installing everything for this web app. I know it's connected to the cloud properly because me and the other dev's `amplify status` output matches, as well as the `amplify env get --name <environment name>` command output.

The error I get every time I do amplify push is:

```
No changes detected
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/gluegun/build/index.js:13
    throw up;
    ^

Error: spawn ENOTDIR
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:394:11)
    at spawn (child_process.js:542:9)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/lib/builder.js:13:28
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/lib/builder.js:6:10)
    at Object.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/lib/publisher.js:9:18)
    at Object.publish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/node_modules/amplify-frontend-javascript/index.js:33:20)
    at Command.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@aws-amplify/cli/src/commands/publish.js:41:29)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5) {
  errno: 'ENOTDIR',
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  syscall: 'spawn'
```

Thanks for any input on how to fix this! I am leery to try too much else on my own because I do not want to accidentally delete what is already in the cloud.

Comment: have you tried running `npm rebuild` in the project root?

Comment: Finally got time at work to try this, and updated npm itself. I am still getting the ENOTDIR error, and error output above. All other amplify commands work like `status` `env pull` etc, just not `publish`

Comment: as in, I tried both `npm rebuild` and updated npm